# Force NetLogo Behaviorspace start running from a specific behaviorspace-run-number

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

So, after a very long time workimg on my NetLogo code, I started running it using Behaviorspace. I saved all my required results for each run until it encountered an error in my code and stopped writing outputs. As the number of runs is so big and it will take so many days repeating the first runs, I was wondering if there is a way I could force NetLogo start from a specific behaviorspace-run-number.

Comment: You can probably alter your `go` (or whatever your main procedure is) code to check [behaviorspace-run-number](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#behaviorspace-run-number) and do a `stop` if it's smaller than the number that your interested in.